# How to invoke PostgreSQL function using spring jdbctemplate instead of direct insert query in Java?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbctemplate

I am new to PostgreSQL. I need to call postgresql function from spring jdbctemplate for storing Employee table details. Below is my code in which I am using insert query to store the Employee details. I need to replace insert query with the Postgresql function-"UpdateEmployee".

```
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate postgressqljdbctemplate;


@Override
public void update(Employee employee) {
String SQL = "insert into employee(Id, name, age, salary) values (?,?,?,?)";
postgressqljdbctemplate.update(SQL, new Object[] { employee.getId(), employee.getName(),
employee.getAge(), employee.getSalary()});
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, the first thing you should do is design that function for insert/update data. Postgres supports many languages for that, but the most popular one is plpgsql.

The function itself might look like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_employee(p_id INT, p_name VARCHAR(255), p_age INT, p_salary DECIMAL)
  RETURNS INT
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
  IF p_id IS NULL
  THEN
    INSERT INTO employee (name, age, salary) VALUES (p_name, p_age, p_salary) RETURNING id INTO p_id;
  ELSE
    UPDATE employee
    SET name = p_name, age = p_age, salary = p_salary
    WHERE id = p_id;
  END IF;
  RETURN p_id;
END;
$$;
```

Now if you call this function with `null` as ID it will insert the data, otherwise data will be found by specified id and updated.

In both cases you'll get the ID of modified record back.

```sql
SELECT update_employee(NULL, 'John', 42, 100000);  -- insert (returns 1)
SELECT update_employee(1, 'John Smith', 42, 200000); -- update previous record
```

Probably it would be better to separate insert function from update, but it is just a sample.

So, with that you can call the function from spring using for example SimpleJdbcCall:

```
final SimpleJdbcCall updateEmployeeCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withFunctionName("update_employee");
final Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("p_id", null);
params.put("p_name", "John");
params.put("p_age", 28);
params.put("p_salary", 150000);

final Map<String, Object> result = updateEmployeeCall.execute(params);
System.out.println(result.get("returnvalue"));
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work if you use Postgresql 12 version and you decalre function.
It's work for procedure,
You can see PgDatabaseMetaData.class, 
line 627, 
your complited sql for `getProcedures` include `p.prokind=p` - only for procedure, but not for function

Answer (score 0):

if you use spring data jdbc, you will call function like this:

```
@Repository 
public interface ExchangeRateRepository extends CrudRepository<ExchangeRate, Integer> {
@Modifying
@Query(value = "call s_pay_dev.p_load_rates(:from::varchar, :to::varchar, :date::date, :time::time, :rate::numeric)")
void saveRateToDB(@Param("from") String from, @Param("to") String to,
                  @Param("date") String date, @Param("time") String time,
                  @Param("rate") Float rate);}
```