# Spring simplejdbc and Postgresql Function with Table Return type

Tags: postgresql, spring-jdbc

I am using PostgreSQL with Spring JDBC Template.

I have a postgressql function that returns a TABLE type. As a standalone the function returns number of records based on input.

Table function looks like below (not exact implementation but a sample)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
search( p_query varchar(20))
RETURNS table (name varchar(20),
 address varchar(100),
salary numeric) 
               
AS $$ 

select name,
address,
salary 
from emp_table
where
upper(name) = upper(p_query);

$$LANGUAGE 'sql';
```

In DAO class, I am making use of simplejdbccall to execute the function.

```
Map<String, Object> results =  simpleJdbcCall.withSchemaName(DB_SCHEMA_NAME)
                    .withFunctionName(SEARCH_FUNCTION)
                    .execute(INPUT_PARAMETERS);
```

There are no errors. However the results is having only one record(the first record).

So I tried with,

```
List<Map<String, Object>> results = (List<Map<String, Object>>) simpleJdbcCall.withSchemaName(DB_SCHEMA_NAME)
                    .withFunctionName(SEARCH_FUNCTION)
                    .execute(INPUT_PARAMETERS);
```

Which resulted in ClassCastException as execute returns a Map.

[How to invoke PostgreSQL function using spring jdbctemplate instead of direct insert query in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44371117/how-to-invoke-postgresql-function-using-spring-jdbctemplate-instead-of-direct-in)

The above solution worked for a single return value but not for table type. Without using Hibernate JPA is it possible to implement this use case.

Note: I have done a similar implementation using Oracle Stored procedure which returns a cursor. Not sure how to make this work with PostgreSQL function. I am a starter
for PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of simplejdbccall, I used a slightly different approach to get the result

i. Used jdbcTemplate.query and written select statement on the Function
ii. Used Rowmapper to map the results into Bean.

Example below.

```
List<TableObjectBean> outputList = jdbcTemplate.query("select name,address,salary from search(?)"
                         ,new Object[] {queryParam}
                         ,new RowMapper<TableObjectBean>() {
                             @Nullable
                             @Override
                             public TableObjectBean mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
                                 TableObjectBean tableObjectBean = new TableObjectBean();
                                 tableObjectBean.setName(resultSet.getString(1));
                                 tableObjectBean.setAddress(resultSet.getString(2));
                                 tableObjectBean.setSalary(resultSet.getDouble(3));
                                 return tableObjectBean;
                             }
                         });
```